# Talend - Process files hosted in a remote machine over FTP

Tags: ftp, talend, getfiles

I want to access a folder in a remote machine (over FTP), and process all the .txt files that folder contains.

I'm doing something like: **tFTPConnection ------> tFTPFileList ------> ? ------> tFileInputDelimited**

How can I than process those files? They are all Delimited files and I have the **((String)globalMap.get("tFTPFileList_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))** variable, but it only gives me the path to each file after "get in" the remote folder that isn't in my computer. It is necessary to copy the files to my computer first? I didn't want to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use iterate connection on the tFTPFileList with: ((String)globalMap.get("tFTPFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")) to the source for the tFTPFileGet

I'll try to create an sample and update this post if you can't solve it.